# How to print the output value in this example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to test the fuzzy logic tipping example that exists at the following link: [click here](http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html)

My question is how can I make this control system prints the output value (tipping) in terms of `['low', 'medium', 'high']` rather than printing the actual computed value.

The following is the example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzzy
from skfuzzy import control

# Universe variables
quality = control.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'quality')
service = control.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'service')
tip = control.Consequent(np.arange(0, 26, 1), 'tip')

# Auto-membership function population (3,5,7)
quality.automf(3)
service.automf(3)

# Custom triangle membership functions
tip['low'] = fuzzy.trimf(tip.universe, [0, 0, 13])
tip['medium'] = fuzzy.trimf(tip.universe, [0, 13, 25])
tip['high'] = fuzzy.trimf(tip.universe, [13, 25, 25])


#view memberships
#quality.view()
#service.view()
#tip.view()


#Fuzzy rules
rule1 = control.Rule(quality['poor'] | service['poor'], tip['low'])
rule2 = control.Rule(service['average'], tip['medium'])
rule3 = control.Rule(service['good'] | quality['good'], tip['high'])



#Control System Creation and Simulation
tipping_ctrl = control.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3])
tipping = control.ControlSystemSimulation(tipping_ctrl)


# Pass inputs to the ControlSystem & compute
tipping.input['quality'] = 10
tipping.input['service'] = 3
tipping.compute()


#visualize & view
print (tipping.output)
tip.view(sim=tipping)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it not as simple as having
`if range1 <= val < range2:
 print "low"
elif range2 <= val < range3:
 print "medium"
else:
 print "high"`

Comment: @NikhilRajawat Thank you for your comment, I 'd probably use your manual way (checking output value against each tipping scales) if there is no way to automate the output using the fuzzy control system (scikit-fuzzy package) itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the tip in this case

```
 tipping.output['tip']
```